# Can I access ECS Fargate Task tags after the Task has exited or stopped running?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I want access to the tags of an ECS Task after it has stopped and the container has exited.

 I launch a task using `aws ecs run-task` and attach a tag to it. I'm able to do this using the `--tags` option in this function, but I can only access the tags until the task completes. Once the task finishes and the container exits, I can't access the tags anymore. Is there a way to get tags of resources that are NOT currently running? 
This is the aws-cli command I'm using to launch a task with tags:

```
aws ecs run-task \
    --cluster ${CLUSTER}\
    --task-definition ${TASK_NAME}-${TASK_ENV} \
    --launch-type FARGATE \
    --network-configuration  "${AWS_VPC_CONFIGURATION}" \
    --tags key='testKey',value='1'\
    --enable-ecs-managed-tags \
;
```

I have tried using `aws ecs list-tags-for-resource --resource-arn ${ARN}` but it only shows tags if the task is still running. If I try this on a task that has already completed/exited with exitcode 0, i get this error

> An error occurred (InvalidParameterException) when calling the
>   ListTagsForResource operation: The specified task is stopped. Specify
>   a running task and try again.

I also tried `aws ecs describe-tasks` but that also returns an empty array once the task has exited - `"tags": [],` and no actual tag values, even though the task was launched with tags.

NOTE: in my use case Task Definitions DO NOT have tags, i'm assigning a tag when the run task command is executed.

Comment: Even running ECS on EC2, the tasks are volatile. They don't hang around for long after failure. You can see info on them for maybe a few hours at best after stop. On Fargate, they seem to get harvested even more aggressively. If you are trying to collect metrics or something, it's probably not a good idea to try and rely on harvesting info from stopped tasks.

Comment: I was trying to pass some information between tasks that a lambda could track, but i found a better way of doing it. Thanks though, good to know that this isn't a good way for metric tracking.

Comment: @tanvi which better way did you use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even running ECS on EC2, the tasks are volatile. They don't hang around for long after failure.

You can see info, like return codes and such, on them for maybe a few hours at best after stop.

On Fargate, they seem to get harvested even more aggressively, so if you are trying to collect metrics or something, it's probably not a good idea to try and rely on harvesting info from stopped tasks. Rather store the info somewhere else more permanent before exiting and retrieve as needed.